# TreeListLookupEdit - Focus Node

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I'm trying to select a node in TreeListLookupEdit.

```
var fn = treeListLookupEdit1.FindNodeByKeyID(NodeId);
treeListLookupEdit1.Properties.TreeList.FocusedNode = fn;
```

My TreeListLookupEdit is already filled with the data (from an EF datasource), I need to focus the desired row and see this value in both treeListLookUpEdit1.Text (when it is in a closed state) and when I open a popup window too.

But nothing happens, it does not selects the node.

I've also tried this (Where "treeNodes" is the actual TreeList inside the TreeListLookupEdit):

```
treeNodes.FocusedNode = fn;
```

But, when I run this piece of code, it works:

```
treeListLookupEdit1.ShowPopup();
treeListLookupEdit1.Properties.TreeList.FocusedNode = fn;
treeListLookupEdit1.ClosePopup();
```

So, how to avoid using the ShowPopup?

**Update**
It seems, you should set EditValue

```
treeListLookupEdit1.EditValue = NodeId
```

Comment: Is there any property like EditingValue?

Comment: Yes, there is an EditValue for TreeListLookupEdit but it does nothing.

Comment: Then i don't think there is any other method to focus tree node without popup the lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up [`TreeListLookUpEdit.Properties.DisplayMember`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditBase_DisplayMembertopic) property and [`TreeListLookUpEdit.Properties.ValueMember`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditBase_ValueMembertopic) property.
Set the `TreeListLookUpEdit.Properties.DisplayMember` property to the column that you want to display in your `TreeListLookupEdit` and `TreeListLookUpEdit.Properties.ValueMember` to ID column and use [`TreeListLookUpEdit.EditValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_EditValuetopic) to focus node.
After that you can do something like this:

```
treeListLookupEdit1.EditValue = fn.GetValue("YourIDColumn");
```

Here is example with `DataTable` as data source:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();

dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Parent_ID", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

dataTable.Rows.Add(1, null, "1");
dataTable.Rows.Add(2, null, "2");
dataTable.Rows.Add(3, null, "3");
dataTable.Rows.Add(4, 1, "1.1");
dataTable.Rows.Add(5, 1, "1.2");
dataTable.Rows.Add(6, 3, "3.1");
dataTable.Rows.Add(7, 3, "3.2");
dataTable.Rows.Add(8, 5, "1.2.1");

var treeListLookUpEdit = new TreeListLookUpEdit();
var properties = treeListLookUpEdit.Properties;

properties.DataSource = dataTable;
properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
properties.ValueMember = "ID";

var treeList = properties.TreeList;

treeList.KeyFieldName = "ID";
treeList.ParentFieldName = "Parent_ID";
treeList.RootValue = DBNull.Value;

Controls.Add(treeListLookUpEdit);

treeListLookUpEdit.Size = treeListLookUpEdit.CalcBestSize();
```

If you set `EditValue` property of this `treeListLookUpEdit` object for example to 5 then you will see "1.2" text in control and node with such text will be focused:

```
treeListLookUpEdit.EditValue = 5;
```

Comment: OP dont want to popup the lookup edit.. will this event fire without popup the lookup edit?

Comment: It will select the node in TreeList, but will not set the value to the actual treeListLookUpEdit1. I will not be able to see the selected value on a closed TreeListLookupEdit

Comment: @Dimitri Do you need to set the value to the actual treeListLookUpEdit1?

Comment: @nempoBu4, My treeListLookUpEdit1 is already filled with the data, I need to focus the desired row and see this value in both treeListLookUpEdit1.Text (when it is in a closed state) and when I open a popup window too.